# How to convert string to array?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I need to convert string

```
"name1", "b", "2", "name2", "c", "3", "name3", "b", "2", ....
```

to an array like

```
$arr[0]['name'] = "name1";
$arr[0]['char'] = "b";
$arr[0]['qnt'] = "2";

$arr[1]['name'] = "name2";
$arr[1]['char'] = "c";
$arr[1]['qnt'] = "3";

$arr[2]['name'] = "name3";
$arr[2]['char'] = "b";
$arr[2]['qnt'] = "2";
```

I used explode to extract an string to array but it not work

Any idea?

Comment: Please post the code you have used.

Comment: $arr = explode(", ", $yourString) must work, post your code please...

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Do you control the generation of the CSV string? If so, using a different delimiter (like ";") between each set would make parsing it alot easier. ie `"name1", "b", "2"; "name2", "c", "3"; "name3", "b", "2"; ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$input = '"name1", "b", "2", "name2", "c", "3", "name3", "b", "2"';
$input = str_replace('"', '', $input);
$input = explode(', ', $input);

$output = array();
$i = 0;
while ($i < count($input)) {
    $output[] = array(
        'name' => $input[$i++],
        'char' => $input[$i++],
        'qnt' => $input[$i++]
    );
}

print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [char] => b
            [qnt] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => name2
            [char] => c
            [qnt] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => name3
            [char] => b
            [qnt] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: [could have edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/3533174/edit) your deleted answer as well

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about the array keys being numeric, you can do:

```
$string = 'name1, b, 2, name2, c, 3, name3, b, 2';
print_r( array_chunk( explode(',', $string), 3 ) );
```